# How does the FOSS exception for MySQL connectors apply to code written in PHP or Python?

Tags: php, licensing, python, gpl

I have looked all over and can't find clear answers to the following:

1. If I write code in PHP or Python that uses GPL MySQL connectors for PHP or Python - which license applies to my code? That of PHP or Python, or GPL?
2. Can I run my PHP or Python code on a server and offer commercial services without the GPL?
3. Can I bundle my PHP code in an application and distribute it commercially without the GPL?

Comment: The GPL doesn't have anything to say about *"commercial"* distribution or services.

Comment: The FOSS Exception doesn't have anything to do with "commercial" distribution or services either.  It is simply a way to allow the connector to be used with other open-source licenses besides the GPL.

Comment: @RobertHarvey So, what is the answer to the above questions? I ask because there is some chatter which says that because of the FOSS exception, GPL does not shift to PHP or Python - thereby what applies to my code is the PHP or Python license (not GPL). Are the answers then Python or PHP, yes, and yes?

Comment: Questions 2 and 3 are meaningless, because the GPL doesn't care about "commercial" use.  Question 1 is irrelevant; the license that applies applies regardless of the MySQL connector or the programming language being used.  In general, the license of the programming language you use is not going to be relevant, and the only difference between the GPL and the MySql Connector license is that they allow you to use other FOSS licenses with it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thanks! So, I guess you are saying that if I am writing my code in PHP or Python, that uses MySQL GPL connectors, I can apply whatever license I like to my software - and redistribute it, or run it on a server.

Comment: No, that's not what I said. :)

Comment: @RobertHarvey Is it possible to answer the last two questions as a "yes" or a "no"? Should be possible. What other details should I provide for someone to answer these questions plainly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GPL - what is distribution?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/162870/gpl-what-is-distribution)